# Compute the goals scored by football teams in their matches in a season, from json data

Tags: java, lambda

**Please look at the Java Stream methods in the for each loop.**

This method totals the score for when the your desired team is playing during the football season - input param teamKey - it is either team1 or team2

I extract score1 or score2, which I total from the Json. The Season object contains, collections of collections of collections.

**My code works, its a case of refactoring my code further**

This method parameter change below does not work, which I want to invoke in the for each loop

```
....
for (Round round: rounds) {
goals += getScoreForTeam(teamKey, round, p -> p.getTeam2().getKey().equals(teamKey), null );
........
private static int getScoreForTeam(String teamKey, Round round, Predicate predicate, ToIntFunction toIntFunction) {
        return Arrays.stream(round.getMatches()).filter(predicate).mapToInt(toIntFunction).sum();
    }
```

Also is it possible to do the processing as one Stream method?

Many Thanks for your help in advance

Json:

```
{
  "name": "English Premier League 2014/15",
  "rounds": [
    {
      "name": "Matchday 1",
      "matches": [
        {
          "date": "2014-08-16",
          "team1": {
            "key": "manutd",
            "name": "Manchester United",
            "code": "MUN"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "swansea",
            "name": "Swansea",
            "code": "SWA"
          },
          "score1": 1,
          "score2": 2
        },
        {
          "date": "2014-08-16",
          "team1": {
            "key": "leicester",
            "name": "Leicester City",
            "code": "LEI"
          },
          "team2": {
            "key": "everton",
            "name": "Everton",
            "code": "EVE"
          },
          "score1": 2,
          "score2": 2
        },.....
```

Working code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Solution {

    // The teamKey is the name of the team eg "arsenal"
    public static int run(String teamKey) {
        /*
         * Write your code below; return type and arguments should be according to the problem's requirements
         */
        Round[] rounds = getSeason().getRounds();
       
        int goals = 0;
        for (Round round: rounds) {
            goals +=  getScoreForTeam1(teamKey, round);
            goals +=  getScoreForTeam2(teamKey, round);
        }
        return goals;
    }

    private static int getScoreForTeam2(String teamKey, Round round) {
        return Arrays.stream(round.getMatches()).filter(p -> p.getTeam2().getKey().equals(teamKey)).mapToInt(i -> i.getScore2()).sum();
    }

    //private static int getScoreForTeam1(String teamKey, Round round, Predicate predicate, ToIntFunction toIntFunction) {
    private static int getScoreForTeam1(String teamKey, Round round) {
        return Arrays.stream(round.getMatches()).filter(p -> p.getTeam1().getKey().equals(teamKey)).mapToInt(i -> i.getScore1()).sum();
    }

    private static Season getSeason() {
        Season season = null;
        try {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            URL url = new URL("https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hackajob-assets1.p.hackajob/challenges/football_session/football.json");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            season = gson.fromJson(result.toString(), Season.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return season;
    }

    class Match {
        private String date;
        private Team team1;
        private Team team2;
        private int score1;
        private int score2;
        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        public Team getTeam1() {
            return team1;
        }
        public void setTeam1(Team team1) {
            this.team1 = team1;
        }
        public Team getTeam2() {
            return team2;
        }
        public void setTeam2(Team team2) {
            this.team2 = team2;
        }
        public int getScore1() {
            return score1;
        }
        public void setScore1(int score1) {
            this.score1 = score1;
        }
        public int getScore2() {
            return score2;
        }
        public void setScore2(int score2) {
            this.score2 = score2;
        }
    }

    class Season {
        private String name;
        private Round[] rounds;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Round[] getRounds() {
            return rounds;
        }
        public void setRounds(Round[] rounds) {
            this.rounds = rounds;
        }
    }
    class Round {
        private String name;
        private Match[] matches;
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Match[] getMatches() {
            return matches;
        }
        public void setMatches(Match[] matches) {
            this.matches = matches;
        }
    }
    class Team {
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String code;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Test harness

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Solution_Test {
    //
    // /!\ Unit Tests are optional but highly recommended /!\
    //
    @Test
    public void testRun() {
      Solution s = new Solution();
      Assert.assertEquals(71, s.run("arsenal"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. The title of the post should explain what the code does rather than what your concerns about the code are. We can't really review the code unless we know what it is doing. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) so that you can improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using a single `getScoreForTeam`

You could replace the `getScoreForTeam1` and `getScoreForTeam2` with a single function that takes a `Predicate` to filter by the appropriate team,
and a `ToIntFunction` to extract the appropriate score.

```
goals += getScoreForTeam(round, m -> m.getTeam1().getKey().equals(teamKey), Match::getScore1);
goals += getScoreForTeam(round, m -> m.getTeam2().getKey().equals(teamKey), Match::getScore2);

// ...

private static int getScoreForTeam(Round round, Predicate<Match> predicate, ToIntFunction<Match> toIntFunction) {
  return Arrays.stream(round.getMatches())
    .filter(predicate)
    .mapToInt(toIntFunction)
    .sum();
}
```

Note some improvements to the sketch in the original code:

- `getScoreForTeam` doesn't need a `teamKey` parameter, the predicate serves that purpose
- `Predicate` and `ToIntFunction` are generic types, they require a type parameter
- When writing code using streams, it's good to break the line before each `.`, so that each logical step is on its own line. It's easier to read code this way, from top to bottom, and not so much sideways.

#### Gson in practice

Gson is very flexible and forgiving.
You don't need to provide setters that are not needed by the users of the parsed classes.
Many of the classes in the posted code can be drastically reduced,
for example:

```
private static class Season {
  private Round[] rounds;

  public Round[] getRounds() {
    return rounds;
  }
}

private static class Round {
  private Match[] matches;

  public Match[] getMatches() {
    return matches;
  }
}

private static class Team {
  private String key;

  public String getKey() {
    return key;
  }
}
```

Notice that I made all these classes `private static`,
which is a good practice:

- `private`: to encapsulate implementation details
- `static`: to avoid unnecessary internal references from inner classes to their enclosing class

#### Use try-with-resources

When working with resources that must be closed after consumed,
make sure to use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) idiom.

#### Implement better exception handling

In the post code,
if something goes wrong when downloading the JSON data,
`getSeason` will return a `null`,
and when code tries to use it,
a `NullPointerException` will be thrown,
which will not give any clue about a problem during download.
It would be better to let the program crash when the download failed,
and print details about what happened.